# Can someone help me solve this problem dealing with area of a sector/circles?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

If a pizza is $1/3$ of an inch thick and has a diameter of $8$ inches, how many cubic inches of pizza have you eaten if you eat a sector whose edges form a $20^{\circ}$angle? Answer to the nearest hundredth of a cubic inch.

^That's the question. I know how to solve it but I don't quite understand why I am doing what I am doing. Can someone please explain step by step what is happening as we are solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fraction of the pizza is a $20^{\circ}$sector?

$$\frac{20^{\circ}}{360^{\circ}} = \frac{1}{18}$$

This means you will have eaten one eighteenth of the total volume of this cylindrical pizza.

What is the total [volume of the cylindrical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_%28geometry%29#Common_use) pizza?

$$ V = \pi r^2 h$$

$$ V = \pi \cdot 4^2 \cdot \frac{1}{3}$$

$$ V = \frac{16 \pi}{3}$$

The volume eaten is one eighteenth of that, or

$$V_{\text{eaten}} = \frac{1}{18} \cdot {\frac{16 \pi}{3}}$$

$$V_{\text{eaten}} = \frac{8\pi}{27}$$

This is in cubic inches, but we want the answer rounded to the nearest hundredth, which is $V_{\text{eaten}} \approx \boxed{0.93}$ cubic inches.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compute the area of the slice and multiply it by the height, that is, $1/3$in.

To compute the area of the slice you have to know the central angle and the radius.

Comment: So you're basically solving for volume?

Comment: I suppose that you want to compute the volume.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the pizza as a really short cylinder.  The volume of the whole pizza is $\pi r^2 h$.  The volume of the wedge you ate is then $(20/360)\pi r^2 h$.  Take the radius as $8/2 = 4$ inches and the height as $1/3$ inch, your answer will be in cubic inches.